# 2013 iMac with APFS Fusion Drive. Fails to boot. How to recover data?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, imac, ssd

I am unable to use Command (⌘)-R to reinstall the macOS, as the system is unable to detect any drives to install the OS.

I have installed the OS X Mountain Lion using an external SSD drive. I get the following errors at start-up. I have ignored the errors as I don't want to format the drives.

[image: Error once you login]

I would like the team to tell me how I can mount the drives and retrieve the data.

One other odd thing I have noticed. The command `diskutil list` will list the internal drives, but after 30 minutes, the 2 TB SSD will not appear in the list. (2 years ago, I replaced the original 3 TB SATA HDD with the current 2 TB SATA SDD.) I have enclosed a screen shot for reference.

I would be very grateful to the community, if I could get a solution. I have some important data (i.e. photos which I need to get back). Foolishly, I have no backup.

[image: Diskutil List After reboot and 30 minutes later]

[image]

Comment: Try `diskutil cs list` instead, which should better list Core Storage devices. Also, could you endeavour to post text as text, rather than pictures. Pictures of text cannot be indexed by google or read by software for the sight-impaired. Copy/paste, select then Ctrl/K to format as 'code'

Comment: Can you boot into target disk mode and read the drive with another machine? What is the state of the latest backup?

Comment: A 2013 iMac should not be able to boot Lion. Did you mean Mountain Lion or perhaps an older Mac?

Comment: OS is Mountain Lion -- iMAC 2013 -- This the only OS supported thiS model of iMac. Backup is not available.

Comment: To answer the query diskutil cs list - output-.   "No Corestorage logical volume group found"

Comment: I believe no 2013 iMacs were shipped from Apple with a 2 TB SSD (or 2 TB HDD). Is the 2 TB drive a replacement SATA SSD drive?

Comment: Year 2013  I bought the iMac it was configured with 128gb ssd and 3tb hdd Drives. fusion drives Fast forward 2021 I rebuilt the system and replaced the 3TB hdd with 2TB ssd drive. It was configured as fusion drive. 2 years later I find myself unable to boot. I plan to replace the current iMac with new m2 MAC mini. The challenge is how can I get data  from the 2tb drive. Arun

Comment: What was the last functioning OS on the Mac? We're only getting the full story in dribs & drabs… but either the core storage is broken [bad news, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75680/what-happens-when-you-remove-or-lose-the-ssd-from-a-fusion-drive/75683#75683 ] or it's formatted APFS, better news but you need an APFS-capable OS on a USB stick or use Cmd/Opt/R for Internet Recovery to be able to see it

Comment: As I am unable to boot the system I cannot be 100% confident what was the functioning OS on the iMac. When I installed the OS on the external SSD it was Mountain Lion. In 2013 I would have re-installed the OS on the iMac and configured Fusion. I would have used default setting to install the OS the iMac.

Comment: Then you'll need to try one of my other suggestions, see if it's APFS rather than a broken core storage

Comment: just checked what file system were available for OS Mountain Lion OS is MacOS Extended (Journaled)   article - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91890/mac-os-x-disk-file-format

Comment: I think these comments got off to the wrong foot when the [initial comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/670556) referenced "Core Storage".  The OS X Mountain Lion `diskutil` command does not recognize the APFS partition type. So instead of posting the string `Apple_APFS`, the `diskutil list` command posts the GUID value read from the drive.  The APFS partition type GUID value is `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`.  See [Apple File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System).

Comment: Core Storage uses an entirely different GUID value which is `53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`. See [Partition type GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs). So there is no Core Storage. This means the Mac has macOS High Sierra, Mojave or Catalina installed on the internal APFS Fusion Drive. You might consider upgrading OS X Mountain Lion on the external drive to macOS Catalina. Can you boot to macOS Internet Recovery by holding down the Option-Command-R key combination at startup? If so, what does `diskutil list` shown when booted from there?

Comment: The point is that you need to be booted from the current macOS Sierra or a newer version of macOS, before you can expect to mount any volumes contained in the APFS Fusion Drive. The fact that replacement SATA SDD disappears from `diskutil list` would indicate to me that there must also be some sort of intermittent and/or permanent hardware failure. So at this point, we do not know if any of the data will be recoverable.

Comment: I have purchased Mac mini M2 this morning. I will try the following boot the iMac using T and then mount drives in the mac Mini. I strongly suspect I have a hardware fault as the 2TB drives does disappear from the system after 30 minutes. If I am unable to mount the drive. I plan to open up the iMac and remove both the drives. Put the drives on a external enclosure and then try and see if I can recover the data. If anyone can further suggest anything that will allow to recover the data please let me know. I will report back on my efforts over the weekend.

Comment: Mac Mini delivery date 5th May. I will post my update after after 5th May.

Comment: I do not understand why you did not upgrade the external drive to a version of macOS that could read APFS fusion drives before taking  steps to remove the drives. You could have at least created a bootable Sierra flash drive installer. Booted from the installer to see if the APFS volumes could be read.