# iMac Late 2012 Unable to boot. Fusion Drive APFS no HFS+

Tags: hard-drive, imac, ssd, apfs, fusion-drive

Reference old question: [2013 iMac with APFS Fusion Drive. Fails to boot. How to recover data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458800/2013-imac-with-apfs-fusion-drive-fails-to-boot-how-to-recover-data/459970#459970)

I have removed both the SSD drives from the iMac. Purchased a new Mac Mini M2 running macOS Ventura 13.3. I bought a caddy to plug the 128GB SSD via USB port on the Mac Mini. Likewise, I purchased a caddy to plug the 2TB HDD into Mac Mini via USB port.

Rebooted the Mac Mini. The good news is that I can see the drive as Fusion on desktop. I can see the directory structure but I am unable to copy the data from the 2TB HDD.

Can somebody help? The drive itself shows no hardware issues.

Terminal -- `diskutil list` output

```
/dev/disk7 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk7
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk7s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk8         121.1 GB   disk7s2

/dev/disk8 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.1 TB     disk8
                                 Physical Store disk7s2
   1:                APFS Volume Fusion - Data           2.0 TB     disk8s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 25.8 MB    disk8s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                526.8 MB   disk8s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk8s4
   5:                APFS Volume Fusion                  11.2 GB    disk8s5
```

The interesting part is that I suspect is the the two drives are not properly fused

```
/dev/disk8 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.1 TB     disk8
                                 Physical Store disk7s2
```

I would expect from the Physical store to have `disk7s2` and `disk8s1`.

When I click on the disk icon on the desktop "Fusion" I can see the directory structure and files in the folders. However when I copy the folder I get error and Zerro Bytes files are copied. I have tried coping the files using the terminal windows CP source to target directory same issue as GUI command.

Calling all people who can help. Somebody must know of a way how I can copy the data to another drive.

I would be grateful if someone could help. If you need any additional information do let me know and I will post the updates.

Apologies I don't have a backup. so recovering the data is the only option I have. trying to find a way I can do it using the help of this group and without the need for professional data recovery people.

I have not deleted any files, Neither formatted the drive. I did try some free trial utility and no data was recovered. I feel the fuse drive needs something to glue it back. As the data is on the disk.

Comment: I have installed free data recovery tools like Easyus and Stellar. No luck I was not able to recover a single file. I have installed UFS Explorer. It's been running for past 4 days "Searching for BeyondRail Metadata". More than 2.7TB of data has been read by the utility. It's found nothing so far and only completed 63% of the scan. not holding out much hope on these data recovery tools... Hope is fading

Comment: The fact that you can “see” the folder structure means the map is intact. However, if the physical spinning drive has failed, the actual files are gone. Remember, on a fusion drive, files aren’t stored on one drive or another, they’re actually stored *across* both drives.  I’ve been down this road several times and couldn’t recover anything substantial.

Comment: 2TB hard drive is Samsung EVO 2TB. I replaced the 3TB HDD which was shipped by Apple with SDD. My system is light use and I am still holding on to the hope the drive is okay from Hardware point of view. Would anyone know if we have a diagnostics utility to check the drive. My other thought process was to clone the 2tb Hard drive. I bought a dual Caddy and it has a function to clone. It may work I will give it a try got nothing to lose.

Comment: There’s nothing built in of any significant diagnostic value.  You could  get [DiskDrill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/data-recovery-software.html), the free version has decent reporting, or [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download) for SMART ststuses

Comment: Arun: You have not posted any output from `diskutil list` for the 2.0 TB Samsung EVO SSD. Can you explain why? The value +2.1 TB was (probably) read from the APFS header stored at the beginning of `disk7s2` partition, but this is not the 2.0 TB Samsung EVO SSD. This SSD should have an identifier that differs from `disk7` or `disk8`.

Comment: Mac mini has 512 gb of internal storage

Comment: /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):/dev/disk3 (synthesized):/dev/disk4 (disk image):
/dev/disk7 (external, physical):
/dev/disk8 (synthesized):

Comment: Device Identifier:     disk8s1
   Device Node:         /dev/disk8s1
   Whole:                    No
   Part of Whole:       disk8
   Volume Name:       Fusion - Data
   Mounted:                Yes
   Mount Point:           /Volumes/Fusion - Data

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Disabled
Disk Size:                 2.1 TB (2121312247808 Bytes)   
I unable to add the entire contents of diskutil info disk8s1

Comment: You can edit it into your question. Select & press Ctrl/k to format as code - like the tables already there.